# Visual Studio / C# compiler extension: LinQ "either X or Y"

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2017, roslyn

Is there a way to create some kind of an extension for VS 2017 or the Roslyn compiler, or whatever, to achive making this LinQ query a bit more pretty?

```
var query = from s in db.TimeSlicedPosts
            where s.Post == post || s.Post == null
            where s.Date == day
            where s.Hour == hour
            select s;
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
var query = from s in db.TimeSlicedPosts
            where either s.Post == post or s.Post == null
            where s.Date == day
            where s.Hour == hour
            select s;
```

Since two or more `where` clauses create an **AND** condition, I would like to have a english-formed way to create an **OR** condition as well, in this case, `either X or Y [or Z, ...]`.

Is that possible to make it in such a way, so that the latter example would be considered as a fully valid C# code, without re-writing and re-compiling Roslyn, but by writing some kind of an extension?

If yes, then where should I start diggin'?

Comment: No, Roslyn doesn't allow you to add plugins to change the grammar of C#. You could fork Roslyn to create your own dialect, but I'd **strongly** advise against it. Aside from anything else, almost all professional C# developers will be able to read and write your first code. You'd have to explain your own custom dialect to everyone who wanted to use your second code.

Comment: You could create a fluent set of extension methods so that it looked like `Where(p => p.post).Or(...).Where(...)`

Comment: You could switch to the extension method syntax, and just write a custom method that returns a bool: `var query = db.TimeSlicedPosts.Where(x => SomeCustomMethod(x));`  This would be cleaner (this is opinion based however), and still not confusing for anyone else to maintain.

Comment: How do you feel about `new[] { null, post }.Contains(s.Post)` ? ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> No, Roslyn doesn't allow you to add plugins to change the grammar of
>   C#. You could fork Roslyn to create your own dialect, but I'd strongly
>   advise against it. Aside from anything else, almost all professional
>   C# developers will be able to read and write your first code. You'd
>   have to explain your own custom dialect to everyone who wanted to use
>   your second code.

– [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)